# Add Facebook Pixel Purchase Event Code to WooCommerce purchase completion page

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, endpoint, facebook-pixel

I need to add the following to the purchase completion page in WooCommerce:

> Copy the event code snippet. You can add parameters to send additional
> on-page data.    fbq('track', 'Purchase');

I tried adding the following code to the child theme functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'qg_enqueue');
function qg_enqueue() {
    if (is_order_received_page()) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            fbq('track', 'Purchase');
        );
    }
}
```

Fatal error. I'm sure I'm messing something up but I'm a little lost. I tried quite a bit of searching. I'm trying to add the script only to the order received page, WooCommerce Checkout endpoint. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are missing quotes in your code inside `wp_enqueue_script()` function, so try to replace `fbq('track', 'Purchase');` with `"fbq('track', 'Purchase');"`, it should solve the error.

Now you should better use [`wc_enqueue_js()` function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.2.1/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L1000-L1013) using `template_redirect` hook as follows:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'enqueue_fbq_purchase_event');
function enqueue_fbq_purchase_event() {
    if ( is_order_received_page() ) {
        wc_enqueue_js( "fbq('track', 'Purchase');" );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.